# Problem with /search tagged and max

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2

Seems like a problem with `/search` when `max` is not set to today, and `tagged` is given:

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/search?order=desc&max=1358294400&sort=activity&tagged=java&site=stackoverflow

The result appears to be empty.

It can be verified through the SO search facility itself that (as expected) there are many, many questions tagged `java` posted at least one day ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed with the latest deploy.

There was a bug introduced in our move to elastic search where min/max was applied *after* paging results, instead of before.  This meant that in any question that would typically have a lot of out-of-range results, the first page would tend to be culled down to nothing.